# How do I plot the square of the amplitude response?

Tags: discrete-signals, finite-impulse-response, frequency-response, transfer-function

I have calculated the transfer function of an FIR filter

$$
y[n] = x[n] + α · x[n − R]
$$
This is what I have
$$
H(z) = 1 + αz^{-R}
$$

Now I should plot the square of the amplitude response. So I calculated the frequency response by inserting **e^jωTs** for **z**. I should choose **α = 1/2** and **R = 3**. So I get

$$
H(e^{jωTs}) = 1 + αe^{-RjωTs} = 1 +  \frac{1}{2} e^{-3jωTs}
$$

$$
|H(e^{jωTs})|^{2} = (1 + αe^{-RjωTs})^{²} = 1 +  \frac{1}{2} e^{-6jωTs}
$$

I am also not sure here about the algebra of the square of the magnitude.

Now I should plot from **0 to ωs** and I think I am missing **Ts**. I should probably just choose a value, right? How is the usual approach?

Comment: You have (at least) one issue with your "squared amplitude" the first equality in the last line does not hold, one should multiply $H()$ by its conjugate

Comment: I don’t know what Ts is but I don’t like it.  Also, that isn’t how you square numbers.  Once you change it to multiply by the complex conjugate, don’t forget to FOIL!

Answer (score 1):

If the impulse response $$h[n]=\delta[n]+\alpha \delta[n-R]\hspace{1cm}=\{1,0,0,...\alpha\}$$ with the ellipsis being R presumably, the Fourier transform $$H(\omega)=e^{-j 0 \omega}+\alpha e^{-jR \omega}=1+\alpha e^{-jR \omega}\hspace{1
cm}\exists\hspace{1
cm}\mathbb{C}$$
where magnitude is defined as $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}=|x+iy|$

Since we want the square of the amplitude response $=|H(\omega)|^2$, we can square the real and imaginary parts of the transform$$\Re{\{H(\omega)\}}^{2}+\Im{\{H(\omega)\}}^{2}\hspace{.5cm}=\hspace{.5cm}(1+\alpha \cos(-R\omega))^{2}+\alpha \sin(-R\omega)^2\hspace{.5cm}\exists\mathbb{R}$$
Then plot from $\omega=[0,\pi)$

Might look something like this with your parameters
[image: graph]

Please tell me if this gives the expected response because I'm relatively new to continuous/algebraic Fourier theory

Comment: Looks like you are using a and alpha interchangeably.  Also you lost your factor of a/alpha on the sine term.